# fontSize is always 17 when load from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uifont

I'm trying to write an `UIFont` extension to increase fontSize when the word display in 5.5 inch iPhone. Hear is my code :

```
public override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let originalSelector = Selector("systemFontOfSize:")
            let swizzledSelector = Selector("systemFontOfFlexibleSize:")

            let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, swizzledSelector)
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }

    }

    class func systemFontOfFlexibleSize(fontSize: CGFloat)->UIFont {
        print(fontSize)
        if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height >= 736.0 {
            return self.systemFontOfFlexibleSize(fontSize + 2)
        } else {
            return self.systemFontOfFlexibleSize(fontSize)
        }
    }
```

This worked well when I use the method `systemFontOfSize` in code. When I use xib or storyboard create a label, `systemFontOfFlexibleSize` still called, but the fontSize is always 17 no matter what I set in storyboard.
Could someone explain this or any other elegant solution?

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had this issue as well a while back, and there seemed there was some kind of weird bug where the font was reseted right after it was set in code. I believe I had to set the font, and afterwards set the font size again for it to work. Below is a code snippet from my project (but this is a bit old so I don't remember if this actually cleared up the issue or if I was having a brain meltdown to write this piece of code):

```
label.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 14.0)
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(14)
```

If I remember correctly I had to set the font size using `fontWithSize()` explicitly or it simply didn't work. Not entirely sure though, but thought you could at least try. I can't really integrate it into your code since I'm not entirely sure what's happening behind the scenes here.

Comment: The question I confused is that I can not get the right label(in storyboard) fontSize when the storyboard load.

Comment: @ZeroChow So you never change the font size in code?

Comment: yes.  `systemFontOfFlexibleSize ` is called when storyboard load, but i get a wrong fontSize